# Python составить условие if

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как в этом коде правильно указать условие, что бы оно работало?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QFrame

class EgoDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)
        self.frame.move(200, 200)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')

        if self.frame.move(200, 200):
            self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = EgoDialog()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста посмотрите документацию pep8, этот кодстайл откровенно ужасен, а касаемо самой конструкции, я так понял это метод который что либо делает, и если у него нет return, то проверить его выполнение можно только по факту, то есть сдвинулся ли фрейм на самом деле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> x() const
>
> Это свойство содержит координату x виджета относительно его родителя

Дополнительно смотрим https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QFrame

class EgoDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)
        self.frame.move(200, 200)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')

#        if self.frame.move(200, 200):
        if self.frame.x() == 200 and self.frame.y() == 200:
        
            self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = EgoDialog()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]